# Can't Acces Categories From Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

I can't access categories from backend and im getting magento's error page with log number. 
Here is my log;

```
a:5:{i:0;s:176:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/local/Meigee/CategoriesEnhanced/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Block/Enabledisable.php, line 1";i:1;s:1371:"#0 /home/petbesin/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/local/Siteground/SuperCacher/Model/Observer/Varnish.php(45): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('X-Cache-Enabled', 'False')
#2 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Siteground_SuperCacher_Model_Observer_Varnish->setCacheFlagHeader(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Siteground_SuperCacher_Model_Observer_Varnish), 'setCacheFlagHea...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('http_response_s...', Array)
#5 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(83): Mage::dispatchEvent('http_response_s...', Array)
#6 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(184): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->sendResponse()
#7 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/petbesin/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/petbesin/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:82:"/index.php/guardianv2/catalog_category/index/key/53c82eadedd4568a85115ced74f3809b/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear: Meigee/CategoriesEnhanced/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Block/Enabledisable.php

The external module you installed sends something to the browser.
Most probably it has a empty line at the start of the file.

Or it is encrypted and you still have to contact the module builder.